How to obtain Chrome complete list of autofill data (for text fields such as username)?
How can I obtain a complete list of autofill data in Chrome browser (not passwords just the other autofill such as username, address, etc for text boxes entered in previously)?
I have attempted to use this guide and viewed the Web Data file however I only have 93 entries in the autofill table which is definitely less than I actually have (several autofill entries show up on Chrome but are not in this table).
Did This: See all autofill data
Also I understand google chrome saves information to the chrome profile/gmail account signed in however not sure how to easily access only the autofill data (I can see google search history under accounts/etc but not autofill).
Can chrome be accessing this information from site specific cookies that it uses to generate autofill data that it does not store in the Web Data file itself?
